# Select All customers with exact name and birthdate

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select all the customers that have the same name and birth date on mysql table.

my query right now is close, but it seems to have a flaw:

```
SELECT
    id,
    customer.name,
    date
FROM
    customer
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        name
    FROM
        customer
    GROUP BY
        name,date
    HAVING
        COUNT(id) > 1
) temp ON customer.name = customer.name
ORDER BY
    name;
```

Comment: What does your question mean?  Please provide sample data and desired results.  A note about English:  expressions that include "the same . . ." often continue with "as".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return a customer if there `EXISTS` another one with same name and date, but other id:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    date
FROM
    customer c1
where exists (SELECT 1 from customer c2
              where c2.name = c1.name
                and c2.date = c1.date
                and c2.id <> c1.id)
```

`JOIN` version:

```
SELECT
    c1.id,
    c1.name,
    c1.date
FROM
    customer c1
JOIN customer c2
  ON  c2.name = c1.name
  and c2.date = c1.date
  and c2.id <> c1.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `EXISTS` expression:

```
SELECT
    id,
    customer.name,
    date
FROM customer c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM customer cc
    WHERE cc.name=c.name AND cc.date=c.date AND cc.id <> c.id
)
```

The meaning of this query can be derived by pretending it's plain English: we are looking for all customers `c` for which there exists another customer `cc` with the same name and birth date, but different `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
select
    c1.*
from 
    customer c1 
    join customer c2 on 
        c1.name = c2.name 
        and c1.birth_date = c2.birth_date 
        and c1.id != c2.id
order by name, birth_date, id
;
```

And here's the full example:

```
drop table customer;

create table customer (
    id int,
    name varchar(64),
    birth_date date
);

insert into customer values (1, 'Joe', '2001-01-01');
insert into customer values (2, 'Joe', '2001-01-02');
insert into customer values (3, 'Joe', '2001-01-03');
insert into customer values (4, 'Jim', '2001-01-01');
insert into customer values (5, 'Jack', '2001-01-01');
insert into customer values (6, 'George', '2001-01-01');
insert into customer values (7, 'George', '2001-01-02');
insert into customer values (8, 'Jeff', '2001-01-02');
insert into customer values (10, 'Joe', '2001-01-01');
insert into customer values (60, 'George', '2001-01-01');

select * from customer;

select
    c1.*
from 
    customer c1 
    join customer c2 on 
        c1.name = c2.name 
        and c1.birth_date = c2.birth_date 
        and c1.id != c2.id
order by name, birth_date, id
;

+ ------- + --------- + --------------- +
| id      | name      | birth_date      |
+ ------- + --------- + --------------- +
| 6       | George    | 2001-01-01      |
| 60      | George    | 2001-01-01      |
| 1       | Joe       | 2001-01-01      |
| 10      | Joe       | 2001-01-01      |
+ ------- + --------- + --------------- +
4 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a table with only id, name and date, you can expand it after that.

The solution is going to be in using an aliased join or an exists clause.

First some code to setup a temporary table with some values for us to query against.

```
--Drop Temporary Test Table if it exists
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Customers_Test', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #Customers_Test; 

--Create a Temporary Test Table
CREATE TABLE #Customers_Test
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Customers_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [id] ASC
    )
    WITH 
    (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF,
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

--Put some temporary values into the table
INSERT INTO #Customers_Test(name, [date])
VALUES ('Joe', GETUTCDATE()),
('Mark', GETDATE()),
('Dan', '1/1/1990'),
('Dan', '1/1/1990')
```

Now for the actual selection styles, there are several ways to do this depending on mostly preferences, if this query had become more complex there may have been a significant run time advantage of one over another.

```
--First Select Version
SELECT  #Customers_Test.id,
        #Customers_Test.name, 
        #Customers_Test.[date]
FROM #Customers_Test
WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM #Customers_Test Duped_Customers
                WHERE Duped_Customers.name = #Customers_Test.name
                AND Duped_Customers.[date] = #Customers_Test.[date]
                AND Duped_Customers.id <> #Customers_Test.id
             )
```

Another way:

```
--Second Select Version
SELECT  #Customers_Test.id,
        #Customers_Test.name, 
        #Customers_Test.[date]
FROM #Customers_Test
INNER JOIN #Customers_Test AS Duped_Customers
ON #Customers_Test.name = Duped_Customers.name
AND #Customers_Test.[date] = Duped_Customers.[date]
AND #Customers_Test.id <> Duped_Customers.id
```

One Final Way:

```
--Third Select Version ( Similar to your current logic).
SELECT  #Customers_Test.id,
        #Customers_Test.name, 
        #Customers_Test.[date]
FROM #Customers_Test
WHERE #Customers_Test.name IN (
                                SELECT name
                                FROM #Customers_Test Duped_Customers
                                GROUP BY name, [date]
                                HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
                              )
```